# Snackbar can't give width and handleClose

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I can't give 100% width on the snackbar and I also have a snackbarClose method but I can't implement it on the snackbar. I also want a button 'X' which button will perform the snackbarClose method.

**CodeSandbox :** https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-kapitsa-f5yd7?file=/src/Demo.js:693-706

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Container, Grid, Button, Snackbar } from "@material-ui/core";
import MuiAlert from "@material-ui/lab/Alert";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const styles = (theme) => ({});

function Alert(props) {
  return <MuiAlert elevation={6} variant="filled" {...props} />;
}

class Demo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      snackbaropen: false,
      snackbarmsg: "",
      severity: ""
    };
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
  }

  onClick = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      snackbaropen: true,
      snackbarmsg: "Data Saved",
      severity: "success"
    });
  };

  snackbarClose = (event) => {
    this.setState({ snackbaropen: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Container>
          <Grid container spacing={2}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={6} lg={6} xl={6}>
              <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
                onClick={this.onClick}
              >
                Submit
              </Button>

              <Snackbar
                open={this.state.snackbaropen}
                autoHideDuration={3000}
                onClose={this.snackbarClose}
              >
                <Alert severity={this.state.severity}>
                  {this.state.snackbarmsg}
                </Alert>
              </Snackbar>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Container>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles, { withTheme: true })(Demo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 100% width on snackbar, you need to specify `width` for `Alert` and `Snackbar` component and for close button you need to specify `onClose` function on `Alert` component.

```
<Snackbar
  open={this.state.snackbaropen}
  autoHideDuration={3000}
  onClose={this.snackbarClose}
  style={{ width: "100%" }}    // specify width 100%
>
  <Alert
    onClose={this.snackbarClose}      // specify onClose method
    severity={this.state.severity}
    style={{ width: "100%" }}    // specify width 100%
  >
    {this.state.snackbarmsg}
  </Alert>
</Snackbar>
```

For snackback closing on outside click, you need to change close function like below:-

```
  snackbarClose = (event, reason) => {
    if (reason === 'clickaway') {
      return;
    }
    this.setState({ snackbaropen: false });
  };
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-khayyam-xo464

Comment: You do not have to adjust style of the SnackBar component if the width of the Alert component is already set to 100%.

Comment: hello @iismaell Please try to remove width from snackbar and try here. https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-khayyam-xo464?file=/src/Demo.js

Comment: hello @Priyank everything is working fine but when I click on a blank spot the snackbar is gone, I don't want that I want when I only click on the button then it's supposed to be gone, or when the snackbar timer is done then it's supposed to go.

Comment: @RafiBhuiyan I have updated my answer about close issue. you can also check demo link.

Answer (score 0):

The SnackBar component delegates to or inherits its style or appearance from its children component, so you can instead adjust the width of the Alert component inside the SnackBar.

```
<Alert style={{ width: "100%" }} severity={this.state.severity}>
   {this.state.snackbarmsg}
</Alert>
```

This should also adjust the width of the SnackBar component and make it fullwidth.

Answer (score 0):

This is so complicated to solve problem.
What React version used?

If you used React(over 16.8), I recommend solution I used.

1. Use `React.createContext`, `React.useContext`
2. Use `React.useReducer`
3. Make custom Hook like `useSnackBar`
4. Mount `SnackBarProvider` on the App

```js
import React from 'react';
import ToastContext, { ToastProps } from './ToastContext';

const useToast = () => {
  const [, dispatch] = React.useContext(ToastContext);

  const message = (toast: ToastProps) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'ADD_TOAST',
      payload: toast,
    });
  };
  return message;
};

export { useToast };
export default useToast;
```

```js
const ToastProvider: React.FC<ToastProviderProps> = ({
  children,
  placement = 'top-right',
  timeout = 5000,
}) => {
  const [toasts, dispatch] = React.useReducer(toastReducer, []);

  return (
    <ToastContext.Provider value={[toasts, dispatch]}>
      <ToastProviderWrapper>
        <ToastProviderContainer className={classnames(placement)}>
          {toasts.map((toast, index) => (
            <ToastCard {...toast} key={index} timeout={timeout} />
          ))}
        </ToastProviderContainer>
      </ToastProviderWrapper>
      {children}
    </ToastContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

```js
const Index = () => (
  <ToastProvider>
    <App />
  </ToastProvider>
);

const rootElement = document.getElementById('root');
ReactDOM.render(<Index />, rootElement);
```

1. You can give data through dispatch(action), reducers
2. You can Dispatch event all the pages.
3. These Doms were rendered Root Element like React.Portal. then you can edit global position styles as system.

Comment: I'm using "react": "^17.0.2"

Comment: Others give you good answer, but I want to give another opinion. I think SnackBar have to render multiple and anywhere.